# brew not able to search common formulas

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I have tried installing and uninstalling brew multiple times on my system, but it is not working for me. It is not even showing results for popular formulas.
I am adding below details.

```
$ brew search cassandra
Error: No formulae or casks found for "cassandra".
```

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.2.8-4-g3573ff8
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 3573ff8d5bf; last commit 2021-08-18)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 03a18c6a5e; last commit 2021-08-18)
```

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.2.8-4-g3573ff8
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 3573ff8d5bf0d3fc4672932ddeb94b65ed6f7b14
Last commit: 3 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
Core tap HEAD: 3573ff8d5bf0d3fc4672932ddeb94b65ed6f7b14
Core tap last commit: 3 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit icelake
Clang: 12.0.0 build 1200
Git: 2.24.3 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.2.3-x86_64
CLT: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
Xcode: N/A
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use brew doctor, and follow the tips that return by the command

```
brew doctor
```

today my meat meet this problem, finally, we deleted the Homebrew directory and reinstalled brew, it is work. maybe because his mac with M1/M2 chip

Comment: kudos for providing the recommendation made by Home-brew maintainers! Reference: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

You must have modified content in `homebrew-core`, or done it by `brew edit`. Anyway, master branch of `homebrew-core` deviated from the remote master. Let's fix it,

```sh
# Cd into homebrew-core repo
cd "$(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"

# Fix remote "origin"
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
git fetch origin master

# Reset current master HEAD to remote origin/master 
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, I deleted the Homebrew directory and reinstalled brew. It worked.